# Parallel groovy script (in Jira via Scriptrunner)

Tags: parallel-processing, jira, gpars

I need to parallelize my script (it creates few subtasks) in Jira ServiceDesk that runs via ScriptRunner. I need to find a way for parallel creation tasks because when SomeUser creates task, it takes a long time for waiting while all subtasks creates. Have any idea how to do it?
I tried to import GPars to my script, but Jira can't find matching method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in another thread/s.

```
Thread.start {
    crateIssue(summary, description)
    crateIssue(anotherSummary, anotherDescription)
}
```

or

```
Thread.start {
        crateIssue(summary, description)
    }
Thread.start {
        crateIssue(anotherSummary, anotherDescription)
    }
```

After you starting thread ScriptRunner forgot about it and immediately returns that post function is ends. User dont be wait when all threads will be finished.

*createIssue is fake function only for example

Comment: Thanks, but know I have a problem with creating subtasks when I use thread. No subtasks are created at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, my fault. Refactoring code is resolved the problem. Thanks!